# PSQL ordering by 1 column but keeping another column grouped

Tags: sql, postgresql

How do I order a table by one column (i.e. `id`) while keeping rows grouped together based on another column (i.e. `name`)?

In my example I would like the query to return rows ordered by `id DESC` first but maintain grouping the rows by name.

*Table:*

```
id |   name 
---+---------
1  | bob
3  | charles
2  | bob
4  | charles
5  | alice
6  | bob
7  | alice
8  | bob
```

*Desired output:*

```
id |   name 
---+---------
8  | bob
6  | bob
2  | bob
1  | bob
7  | alice
5  | alice
4  | charles
3  | charles
```

Comment: Use `ORDER BY` to specify the result set order.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM YourTable t ORDER BY t.name,t.id DESC`. Though this will show alice first. Do you really want this specific ordering?

Comment: However, alphabetic order is much easier than bob, alice, charles. How do you decide that order???

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
select * from table_name
order by max(id) over(partition by name) desc, id desc
```

The names with the biggest `max(id)` will come first, ordered by `id desc`.

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=52a2c92b2228cfb214401e892069f527)